# ckeditor on focus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Just trying to do a simple on focus command with ckeditor and jquery.

```
var foo = // what can i do here to signal ckeditor?
$(foo).focus(function(){
  $(".class1").hide();
  $(".class2").show();
});
```

Maybe this is really simple and I'm just overlooking it but any advice or links are greatly appreciated.

Have tried:

[CKEditor on focus remove default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137958/ckeditor-on-focus-remove-default-value)

[How to listen to basic events in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721916/how-to-listen-to-basic-events-in-ckeditor)

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-method-constructor

http://www.mytechlogy.com/professionals/questions/forum-details/158/how-to-make-focus-in-ckeditor-using-js/?ref=related_posts#.U2EgUv3z3eI

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/jquery-click-event-not-working-textarea-ckeditor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea with CKEditor's events

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (event) {
    event.editor.on("focus", function () {  //nothing to do with jQuery, this is CKEDITOR's on
        $(".class1").hide();
        $(".class2").show();
    }
);
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.instances["editorID"].on("focus", function(){  //CKEDITOR's ON
    $(".class1").hide();
    $(".class2").show();
} );
```