# CKeditor on focus ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ckeditor, focus

I use ASP.NET with CKeditor (4.3).
Unfortunately I am not able to get "on focus" working.

**ASPX code**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorID" Text='<%# Bind("foo")%>' runat="server" Width="100%" Height="200px" CustomConfig="/config.js" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**config.js**

```
 CKEDITOR.on('focus', function () { alert('focused'); });
```

There is no alert fired.
I will be glad for any help.
Thanks a lot
Miroslav

Comment: Can you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393093/ckeditor-on-focus-not-working