# CKEditor on focus CSS change

Tags: javascript, symfony, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in a symfony project with the `FOS\CKEditor-bundle 1.2`. I would like the whole elment that includes a CKEditor to have a border on focus, similar to how you write or answer a question on Stackoverflow. 
Using an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393093/ckeditor-on-focus-not-working) and a JSFiddle, i've gotten this far:

**Js**

```
// Set focus and blur listeners for all editors to be created.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    var editor = evt.editor,
        body = CKEDITOR.document.getBody();

    editor.on( 'focus', function() {
        // Use jQuery if you want.
        body.addClass( 'fix' );
    } );

    editor.on( 'blur', function() {
        // Use jQuery if you want.
        body.removeClass( 'fix' );
    } );    
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar',
    on: {
        // Focus and blur listeners can be set per-instance,
        // if needed.
        // focus: function() {},
        // blur: function() {}
    }
} );
```

Or as a [demo of JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL3nhvxw/1/). Everything looks alright on the fiddle, however with my version of CKEditor the border is actually set on the `body` of the main page and nog the CKEditor.

I don't understand why it won't work or what to change. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CKEDITOR.document` is equivalent to `window.document` (not the same because ). If you want to add class to `body` element of specific editor instance, use `editor.document.getBody();`.

Another problem is that `body` of editor instance is kept inside internal document so if you want the `fix` class to have an effect, you need to add it to e.g. `ckeditor/contents.css` or a file assigned to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss.

I also would recommend replacing the default `margin:20px;` from `body` rule with   `padding: 20px; margin : 0;`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments I think, a better approach would be:

```
        <style>
            .fix {
                border: 5px solid black !important;
            }
        </style>
        ...
        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {/*instance configuration goes here*/});
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {

            var main_container = document.getElementById( 'cke_' + evt.editor.name ),
                content_container = main_container.getElementsByClassName( 'cke_contents' )[0];

                editor.on( 'focus', function() {
                    content_container.classList.add( "fix" );
                } );

                editor.on( 'blur', function() {
                    content_container.classList.remove( "fix" );
                } ); 
        } );
```

**NOTES:**

- The style rule can be put into CSS file but in this case this needs to be main page CSS file and not `contents.css`
- It is necessary to add the `!important` to border in your fix class because editor's `cke_reset` sets it to 0. You can also add it as inline style.

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/j_swiderski/pen/XyMyme

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but there is an issue. The border is now only around the paragraph of what you are entering it seems (so it runs though the text area).

Comment: You said you wanted it around CKEditor body so that what the code does.  Please note if there is no content inside the body, it will have the size of one line. You may work around it by adding inside `contents.css` e.g. `min-height:200px`. Please also remember about replacing `margin:20px` with `padding: 20px; margin : 0;`. If this is not what you want, you may try adding that border around div with class `cke_contents` which is the container for whole content area but in that case you need to add it as inline style and not as a class.

Comment: I get what you saying and you are right. With this solution though (i did everything just like you said) I will have a border shown on three sides (left, right and bottom) even with a different z-index. More problematic is the fact that if you do happen to have a height that extends the 200px (for example) the border is not responsive, so the text runs through it. I'm going to try your second suggestion.

Comment: I have added an extra solution that might work for you.

Comment: I thank you for all the help, but I'm afraid it does not work. I have managed to find a solution though which I will post here as an answer.

Comment: The code snippet I have given you in the EDIT works 100%. I have checked in `ckeditor/samples/old/replacebycode.html` it before posting it. i have also added a working example.

Comment: You must be right, because I checked with a jsfiddle and it worked. Somehow with my renderen HTML it doesn't. I have an example of my html here: https://jsfiddle.net/0xf4z72v/

Comment: There is a lot of garbage in that sample code. Here is the working version https://jsfiddle.net/4qrhnatd/. If you are not assigning the editor instance to variable like so `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace` then inside the `instanceReady` event handler you need to find another way of getting into that instance. One of such ways is `evt.editor` which is what I did (apart from cleaning the garbage) to get that code working.

Answer (score 0):

In the CKEditor when you focus on the text area, it gets an added class `cke_focus`. Using this class and the second `div` element with id `cke_1_contents` you can create some css to create a border on the contents (the text area), when focused on. Like this:

```
.cke_focus #cke_1_contents {
            border: 5px solid black !important;
}
```

Like Swiderski says: It is necessary to add the !important to border in your fix class because editor's cke_reset sets it to 0. You can also add it as inline style.

Comment: Please note that if you have more than one editor on your page this solution will no longer be valid because the ID will be different. What is more, if you destroy and create editor instances dynamically like e.g. here http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-11-22-07-04/full/samples/old/ajax.html your solution will only work for the first editor. With the code I have given you you can have as many editors as you like.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this in 2022...

I had a need to customize the regular border and the border upon focus for a CKEditor 4 instance in React. I had do this from a parent component that consumed a wrapper component around CKEditor. I didn't want to modify the wrapper or the CKEditor instance directly, or create a `contents.css` file, since the wrapper was used in other parts of the app and I wanted the lightest of touches. The style overrides that worked for me looked something like this (note that I was using material-ui and JSS syntax, but the principle is the same):

```css
.parent-container {
  .cke {
    border: 2px solid #111111 !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
  }

  .cke.cke_focus {
    border-color: #222222 !important
  }
}
```